OLEDB connection with user access token fails with DBPROP_INIT_PROMPT message
I have an Excel Add-In that connects to an Azure SQL DB to fetch some data using an OLEDB connection. The connection string structure is as follows
connString = "OLEDB;" +
        "Provider=MSOLEDBSQL" + ";" +
         "Data Source=" + serverName + ";" +
         "Initial Catalog=" + dbName + ";" +
         "Access Token=" + token + ";" +
         "Application Name = " + AppConst.DEFAULT_NAME + ";";

The token property in the string above is a user token that is generated on behalf of the logged in user. It represents a user that has sufficient permissions on the target database.
This connection works without any issue on one of my Azure SQL databases, but for a couple others it fails with the following error -->
Access Token authentication option can only be used with DBPROP_INIT_PROMPT property set to DBPROMPT_NOPROMPT
The calling user exists with the same permissions on all my Azure SQL databases and all databases are configured similarly. Is there something at the DB level like a config or setting that I might have missed?

Access Token authentication option can only be used with DBPROP_INIT_PROMPT property set to DBPROMPT_NOPROMPT

when the OLEDB connection is unable to establish a connection to the Azure SQL Database then you may get the above error, along with that connection string format, network connectivity issues may cause above error. To resolve the error, follow below instructions:
Make sure you have given the connection string in correct format as shown below:
connString = "OLEDB;Provider=SQLNCLI11;Server=<serverName>.database.windows.net;Database=dbname;Uid=userid;Pwd=password;"

Check the user permissions by connecting to SSMS or Azure data studio with required details as shown below:

Make sure you are able to Azure SQL database server is allowing your network. For more information you can refer to the document.
